# Функция запятой в конкретном предложении: разделяет или выделяет?

Tags: пунктуация

Есть предложение из тренировочных тестов к ЕГЭ:

***Более общее название этих построек – мегалиты, «большие камни».***

Вопрос:

**Какова функция запятой в этом предложении: она разделяет однородные члены или выделяет, обособляет словосочетание "большие камни"?**

Чтобы было понятно, почему возник такой вопрос у меня, формулирую задание 21 из ЕГЭ: *"Найдите предложения, в которых запятая ставится в соответствии с одним и тем же правилом пунктуации".*

Я считаю, что запятая в данном предложении выполняет функцию выделения, обособления.

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ. Добавлю список предложений для полной ясности:

**(1)Уникальной достопримечательностью Кавказа являются дольмены. (2)По словам ученых, их возраст составляет около 9 тысячи лет. (3)Дольмен – древнее сооружение из камней, средний вес которого – 70 тонн (4)Более общее название этих построек – мегалиты, «большие камни». (5)Археологами установлено, что дольмены строились в эпоху бронзы. (6)Внутри дольменов исследователи находили черепки глиняной посуды, наконечники скифских стрел, обломки античных амфор, иногда они натыкались на древние захоронения.
(7)Некоторые исследователи считают, что дольмены – это могильники, но вовсе не во всех дольменах были обнаружены захоронения. (8)Другие исследователи подозревают, что дольмены – культовые сооружения. (9) Существуют и совсем экзотические версии, по которым дольмены – детища пришельцев из других миров, зародивших жизнь на нашей планете.**

Comment: Наткнулся на предложение (2) в этом задании и понял, что ничему хорошему такие задания не научат: _(2)По словам ученых, их возраст составляет около 9 **тысячи** лет._ 

https://infourok.ru/prakticheskij-material-k-zadaniyu-21-ege-russkij-yazyk-4037386.html

Comment: Меня утешает только то, что это  тренировочные тесты. Опытный учитель увидит всё и подскажет ученику, но если ученик занимается самостоятельно...

Comment: Это подстава, чтобы дети не занимались самостоятельно. И про правило непонятно. В задании вроде две выделительные запятые (вводное выражение и уточнение), а это сколько правил (одно или два)? В смысле это разные правила или одно и то же? Такие надуманные формулировки только мешают обучению и отвлекают от знаний.

Comment: Совершенно с вами согласна.

Comment: А не обратили внимания на то, что там предложения 35789 - все сложноподчинённые и запятые там поставлены в соответствии с одним правилом пунктуации?

Comment: Да, конечно, обратила внимание, и правильный ответ мы дали. Но я прошу ученицу объяснить ВСЕ запятые из этого задания. Вот почему возник вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Более общее название этих построек – мегалиты, «большие камни».***

Общим названием, вероятно, следует считать ***мегалиты***, а "большие камни" поясняет это название, можно подставить союз ТО ЕСТЬ. Тогда это обособление, запятая выделительная. В конце предложения она попадает в позицию неразличения с разделительной запятой, но функцию можно обозначить интонационно – по наличию или отсутствию перечислительной интонации.

Для сравнения: *Эти постройки называют по-разному: мегалиты, большие камни.*

Тогда это однородные члены, запятая разделительная.

Примечание: Пояснительный союз ТО ЕСТЬ, как я думаю, пропустили намеренно, чтобы усложнить учебное задание. В обычном тексте его надо бы поставить.